# How to Enable pg_stat_statements module in postgresql(9.4)

Tags: postgresql

I have installed postgres database of version  **9.4.1**  through  source code method ( not by rpm installation) so left out the option of installing postgresql-contrib,

Now i need to enable the module  pg_stat_statements.On googling got suggestions  that  need to create statement as `create extension pg_stat_statements;`

While executing i Got the error  as

`create extension pg_stat_statements;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_Postgres/Scripts_Dir/share/postgresql/extension/pg_stat_statements.control": No such file or directory`

While checking the particular location noted that there is no pg_stat_statements.control and  sources suggested me to install postgresql-contrib before creating extensions.

Hence proceeded with

`rpm -Uvh http://yum.postgresql.org/9.4/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-centos94-9.4-1.noarch.rpm
yum install postgresql-contrib`

It has been installed succesfully but again  got same error while creating extensions .

**Where does the changes needed to install module under the /opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_Postgres/Scripts_Dir/share/postgresql/extension/ directory

or what should be the measure taken to enamble the pg_stat_statements module.

It may be basic one but please do help on this

Answer (score 3):

for the postgrersql10 I have solved it with

```
yum install postgresql10-contrib
```

dont forget to activate extensions in postgresql.conf

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'
pg_stat_statements.track = all
```

then of course restart

```
systemctl restart postgresql-10.service
```

all of the needed extensions you can find here

```
/usr/pgsql-10/share/extension/
```

---

so if you will take this extra 10 in the filename it should work
eg:

```
 yum install postgresql-contrib
```